# Enable SSO for my application

Tags: tomcat, single-sign-on

I own a reporting application deployed on Apache Tomcat. Now, it is decided by the mgmt that my application should not have a explicit login i.e,they would login to their machine using some (using webseal) authentication, and when they access a link, my application should open up with the Home Page (not the Login Page)

Relevant teams would take up the activity of configuring which all applications should use SSO. We have very little info on this.

Now, I'm trying to understand what changes need to be done in MY Tomcat server configuration file server.xml to make sure my applictaion does not ask for a Login Page when the user is already authenticated.

Comment: Are you in an Active Directory environment.

Comment: I have not integrated AD to my application yet.Its appliction level authentication to login.